# How to Pass ID to MVC ActionResult using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, post

How do I pass the id retrieved from radiobuttonfor to MainPage controller - Edit1 actionresult in View. Anyhelp will be appreciated! Thanks!

//View in for loop to display contents and radiobutton

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SurveyTitle)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateCreated)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateClosing)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.SurveyId, new {id = item.SurveyId})
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }


          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="edit">Edit</button>
```

//Script for button to detect which radiobutton id is selected and submit

```
<script>            
        $('#edit').click(function () {

            var id = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
            alert(id);


        });

         </script>
```

//Controller to get the id and take surveyid out

```
[HttpPost]
             public ActionResult Edit1(int id=0)
            {
                survey survey = db.surveys.Single(s => s.SurveyId == id);
                if (survey == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View(survey);
            }
```

Comment: I need to clarify what you are trying to do...I keep editing my answer b/c I'm not quite sure what you want to accomplish.  Are you trying to navigate to a edit form based upon the selected radio button?

Comment: i'm trying to allow user to select a radiobutton and click submit button and it will go into that method with the id and do the necessary stuff and eventually return a page with the id. But problem now is the id don't work.

Comment: Add the relevant parts of your view to the question.

Comment: added to the question already.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Or place your id to some hidden text field and trigger click on submit button (if you have web-form on a page)

Comment: I have tried this, it did go into the method but the id is always 0. however whenever i use alert to debug there are values.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to change the window's location when the user clicks edit based upon a particular id set by a radio button list.

I think you'd be able to do something like this:

```
$('#edit').click(function () {

    var id = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
    window.location.href='/MainPage/Edit1/'+id;
    //window.location.href='/MainPage/Edit1/?id='+id; //if {controller}/{action}/{id} isn't setup in the routing class.

});
```

Comment: ur method works if i put it as static value. But how to i get the id of radiobutton if it is dynamic? Like when user select 1 radio button and click on the button.

Comment: the problem is with the id, it won't work, not sure why but if i set it to static value, it works.

Comment: @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.SurveyId, new {@id = item.SurveyId}) is this part something wrong?

Comment: If you place an alert before the use of id in the js, what shows up?  It looks like you are setting the id of the radio button to the survey id, but the code is looking for the val() of the checked button, not the id.  You could change it to var id = $('input[type=radio]:checked').attr("id"); in that case.

Comment: the alert will return 'id = somenumber', and .attr("id") returns item_SurveyId

Comment: I'm assuming 'somenumber' and 'item_SurveyId' are actually integers...in which case, I don't see any reason why these wouldn't work.  One thing though.  If you are using window.location.href you aren't posting...so you may need to remove [HttpPost] from the controller.

Comment: yea by right it wud work but the id is 0 when reach the controller. duno y too.

Comment: Or is this part @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.SurveyId, new {@id = item.SurveyId}) wrong?

Comment: if you do alert('/MainPage/Edit1/'+id); and comment out the window.location.href what shows up?

Comment: I had found the problem because id is a string, i need to convert it to int. But now I encounter another problem which is the View(survey), it enters it but no view is return on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this submit button you speak of? Is it `#edit`? You need to let it POST the form if you want to reach a POST action. Also, it won't bind to `int id` in your action unless you change the radio to something like `@Html.RadioButton("id", item.SurveyId)`

Comment: yea it is a post button, i duno y stackoverflow don't allow me to edit, keep prompting me with some error

Comment: ok edited, i tried @Html.RadioButton("id", item.SurveyId) but item.SurveyId should b int? but it is string